# How to get elements from dropdown when input type is not ' select' in selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selenium

I have a  button with javascript function to display dropdown items and NOT the usual select box. I need to extract all items listed in this dropdown and export to exel sheet. Items listed under following button are of type 'checkbox'.Im using selenium webdriver.
This is the HTML code:

```
<input  id="selServicesBtn"  value="SELECT OPTION" onclick=" checkBoxDisp();" type="button">
<i class="fa fa-filter" id="FilterIcon"></i>
<div name="chkToggleWindow" id="chkToggleWindow" class="chkToggleWindow" style="display: block;"> 
    <div name="checkboxTagEnclosed" class="checkboxTagEnclosed"
id="checkboxTagEnclosed"> 
        <table name="checkboxTag" class="chkbxtag" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="0" onchange=" checkOnchange();">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input id="checkBox_00" type="checkbox" value="OPTION1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="0" _bst_unchecked="false" name="checkboxTag" onchange=" checkOnchange();">
                        <label for="checkBox_00">OPTION1</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input id="checkBox_01" type="checkbox" value="OPTION2" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="0" _bst_unchecked="false" name="checkboxTag" onchange=" checkOnchange();">
                        <label for="checkBox_01">OPTION2</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

This is what I tried:`

```
WebElement table_element = driver.findElement(By.name("checkboxTagEnclosed"));
List<WebElement> tr_collection=table_element.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='checkboxTagEnclosed']/table/tbody/tr"));

System.out.println("NUMBER OF ROWS IN THIS TABLE = "+tr_collection.size());
int row_num,col_num;
row_num=0;
for(WebElement trElement : tr_collection)
{
    List<WebElement> td_collection=trElement.findElements(By.xpath("td"));
    System.out.println("NUMBER OF COLUMNS="+td_collection.size());
    col_num=0;
    for(WebElement tdElement : td_collection)
    {
        System.out.println("row # "+row_num+", col # "+col_num+ "text="+tdElement.getText());
        col_num++;
    }
    row_num++;
}
```

I am getting row and column count but text is null.

[image: output scrnshot]

Not able to get the contents of dropdown.Please help.

Comment: So you want Option 1 and Option 2 in text?

Comment: yes. I want option1 and option2 in text

Comment: Pls do tell me if I have to use completely different approach other than xpath

Comment: Just try to do a `gettext()` for the following and let me know what is coming:
`.//label[@for='checkBox_01']`

Comment: `driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//label[@for='checkBox_01']")).gettext();`

Comment: should this not be by tag name "td" instead of xpath? List<WebElement> td_collection=trElement.findElements(By.xpath("td"));

Comment: Shank has a point.
`List<WebElement> td_collection=trElement.findElements(By.xpath("td"));`
should be 
List<WebElement> td_collection=trElement.findElements(By.tagname("td"));

Comment: @KishanPatel driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//label[@for='checkBox_01']"))‌​.gettext(); is showing syntax error

Comment: @shank087 I tried changing to tagname....but getting same result. text value is null

Comment: `driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//label[contains(text, 'OPTION1' )]"))‌​‌​.gettext(); ` Try

Comment: This didn't work.It returned null pointer exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way.

```
List<WebElement> dropdpwn = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='checkboxTagEnclosed']/table[@class='chkbxtag']/..‌​//following::input[@‌​type='checkbox']"));   // Using list web-element get all web-elements.
System.out.println(dropdpwn.size());              

for(int i = 0; i<dropdpwn.size(); i++)           
{
   System.out.println(dropdpwn.get(i).getAttribute("value"));   //Using for loop getting one by one dropdown name using value attribute.
   Thread.sleep(2500);                          //wait for 2.5 seconds
}
```

Comment: Yes I tried the code...It is working!!! I got the result I wanted but there is a catch. I got results from other checkboxes in the page too. How to filter that out?

Comment: Alright, then You need to modified your `xpath`, so it won't affect another `checkboxes` in same page.

Comment: Please Mark this answer as `Accepted` if its resolved your issue.

Comment: I gave xpath as : By.xpath("//*[@id='checkboxTagEnclosed']input[@type='checkbox']"); Its not working. Can you pls tell me how to give the right xpath for div checkboxTagEnclosed selecting all checkboxes

Comment: Its not working. I am geting dropdown size as 0 when I give this xpath

Comment: Try this xpath `//div[@id='checkboxTagEnclosed']/table[@class='chkbxtag']/..//following::input[@type='checkbox']`  it will surely work for you. I have try this on my end, it is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
List<WebElement> td_collection=trElement.findElements(By.xpath("td"));
```

with

```
List<WebElement> td_collection=trElement.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
```